# Map two separate objects in new class with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, automapper, ienumerable

I have 2 models, `Products` and `Categories`, these are from the model on the repository:

```
IEnumerable<Product> 
IEnumerable<Category>
```

I create a WebAPI and introduce AutoMapper eventually having code as below to return the products and categories in their own separate classes

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
....
public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        try
        {
            IEnumerable<Product> products = GetProducts();
            var mappedResult = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ProductModel>>(products);

            return Ok(mappedResult);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

As i say same code in a new class for Category. Notice the new model for this class so its separate from the Domain model (`ProductModel`).

I now would like to create a page in my MVC application (not .Net Core) which needs to display a list of categories in a dropdown and list the products with a foreach loop. I create a new class as below

```
Public Class ProductsAndCategoriesModel
{
        public ProductModel Products { get; set; }
        public CategoryModel Categories { get; set; }
}
```

The idea here is to have a new method to load the same products and categories data but in its own class. Im following the same convention as above but how do i map two different data sources to this one class using AutoMapper?

```
            var mappedResultProducts = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ProductsAndCategoriesModel>>(products);
            var mappedResultCategories = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ProductsAndCategoriesModel>>(cats);

            //return Ok(mappedResult);
```

I need to map products to Products found in ProductsAndCategoriesModel and Categories found in ProductsAndCategoriesModel. I tried to pass in categories but couldnt as it threw a compiler exception. How could i achieve this?

**Edit 1**

```
    public ProductCategoryProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Product, ProductsAndCategoriesModel>();
        CreateMap<Category, ProductsAndCategoriesModel>();
    }
```

Comment: Would be great if you can share the MapperConfiguration or (Mapping) Profile to the question. What is the exception you get? Without it, we can't know what is your actual problem.

Comment: Ah hold on, do you mean i need to create a new mapping profile? I have these mapped for Product and Category in their separate profile             CreateMap<Product, ProductModel>();
            CreateMap<Category, CategoryModel>();

Comment: Do you have any mapper configuration/profile that try to map from `ProductModel` to `ProductsAndCategoriesModel` and `CategoryModel` to `ProductsAndCategoriesModel`?

Comment: But it is weird that you create `ProductsAndCategoriesModel` class. If you map from `ProductModel` to `ProductsAndCategoriesModel`, does the `Categories` property will contain value? Same goes for `CategoryModel` to `ProductsAndCategoriesModel` for the `Products` property.

Comment: Ive just added the above profile under Edit 1. I have a Product and Category with separate mapping in separate profiles. I did this as that code is used in other parts of the site. For this one page i want a list of Categories and display all products. This way i can foreach the Products on the HTML page and use DropDownListFor(pass_in_Categories) on the same page. If there is a way to combine them all then that would be useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to make things more complicated than they should be. Why don't you simply do it like this:

Model class:

```
public Class ProductsAndCategoriesModel
{
    public IEnumerable<ProductModel> Products { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CategoryModel> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping profile:

```
public ProductCategoryProfile()
{
    CreateMap<Product, ProductModel>();
    CreateMap<Category, CategoryModel>();
}
```

Controller:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    try
    {
        IEnumerable<Product> products = GetProducts();
        IEnumerable<Category> categories = GetCategories();

        var result = new ProductsAndCategoriesModel
        {
            Products = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ProductModel>>(products),
            Categories = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CategoryModel>>(categories)
        }

        return Ok(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return InternalServerError(ex);
    }
}
```